# cannot deploy webapp converting securitycontextlogouthandler to logouthandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am having problems with a bean when setting a property.
I am using springsource 3.2.5 with spring-security

What am I missing? 
I am giving maintenance to this code, so I don't quite understand why I can't make it work.

The stack trace is as follows:

> Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler] to required type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler] for property 'logoutHandlers[0]': no matching editors or conversion stra
>   tegy found
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:128)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:466)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:488)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1463)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:623)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
>       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)

What may be causing the problem?

I have this on my configuration xml:

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:/securityContext.xml,
        classpath*:/localSecurityContext.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

securityContext.xml

```
<beans:bean id="logoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" lazy-init="false" />

<beans:bean id="cookieLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.CookieClearingLogoutHandler" lazy-init="false" >
    <beans:constructor-arg value="SSRMC"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="concurrentSessionFilter"
    class="mx.org.ife.rfe.siirfe.comun.usuariologin.authenticator.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter" lazy-init="false" >
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/" />
    <beans:property name="logoutHandlers" >
        <beans:list value-type="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler">
            <beans:ref local="logoutHandler"/>
            <beans:ref local="cookieLogoutHandler"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Does removing `value-type="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler"` help?

Comment: No. I actually added it in the hope to get some extra information from the log output, but I got the same.